# Use casperjs to get all links from a page

Tags: javascript, regex, casperjs

I need to use casperJS and phantomJS to get only the links from both `a` `href` attribute and `img` `src` that start with http,https,ftp or ftps (I suppose that this is the regex that should be used: `((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/[^"]+)"/g)`.

I implemented the code that gets the links only from the `a` tags, but I need to improve it to also get the links from `img` tags that match the regex...

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links;

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('src')
    });
}

casper.start('https://marvel.com');

casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function () {
    for(var i in links) {
        console.log(links[i]);
    }
    casper.done();
});
```

Comment: I don't know casperjs, but your regex looks good. I just add a quick note: you can compact `http|https|ftp|ftps` to `https?|ftps?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string provides the `match` function where you can evaluate a Regular Expression against. It returns the matches as an array or `null` if there were no matches.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var regex = /((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/[^"]+)"/g)/;
    var srcs = this.getElementsAttribute("img", "src").filter(function(src){
        return !!src.match(regex);
    });

    srcs.forEach(function(src){
        console.log(src);
    });
});
```

This regex doesn't look right to my eye, so I'd use `var regex = /^(ht|f)tps?:\/\//;`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171792/generate-har-file-from-array-of-links-using-phantomjs ? 
I need to generate multiple har files for each link from an array and I really need some help with this ...

Comment: Pavel, please don't beg like this. I've seen your question and I don't see why you can't use Vaviloffs suggestion of the duplicate question. It should be easy. You haven't tried it yet.